# Setting user-agent in phantomjs with selenium webdriver causing previously working page to fail

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless

I am using phantomJS on top of selenium.webdriver in C# to scrape a website.  Originally, I did not set the user agent to anything, and was able to interact with page enough to get past login form.  However, I got stuck when trying to get the contents of an iframe.  It keeps coming back empty, so I suspect its because the site only works on IE.  However, I really want headless browser, so I am attempting to get this to work by setting the user-agent string to that of IE 11.

```
 PhantomJSOptions opts = new PhantomJSOptions();
 opts.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
 browser = new PhantomJSDriver(opts);
```

Now, though, I can't get past login page, it barfs out with

```
"errorMessage":"'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'B(A(a)).getComputedStyle(a,null).MozTransform.match')" etc...
```

I'm not sure what to do, can anyone advise as to what's really going on?

Comment: Probably selenium engine was not able to set focus on iframe.
try switching your focus to iframe and then perfrom your actions

Comment: Thanks for replying.  There is no frame in the login screen.